# C sum of Squares from linked list

Tags: c, recursion, linked-list

Hello im trying to make a program that takes a linked list of integers and sums the squares of the int, using recursion. I have tried this so far, however i cant get the function of summin the squares to work. I dont know if using the pow() is the best way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <assert.h> 
#include<math.h>

typedef struct node
{
  int value;
  struct node* next;
} node;

/* terminal node at the end of the list */
node SENTINEL = {0, 0};

/* utility functions to create and free lists */
node * make_node(int v, node * q)
{
  node* p = (node*) malloc(sizeof(node));
  p->value = v;
  p->next = q;
  return p;
}

int sum_squares(node* list)
{
    if(list == 0)
        return 0;
    else
    {
        return(pow(&list, 2) + sum_squares(list));
    }
    
    
}
void free_node(node* p)
{
  if(p == &SENTINEL)
    return;
  else
  {
    free_node(p->next);
    free(p);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
    int sum;
    node* list =    
        make_node(1,
            make_node(2,
                make_node(3,
                    make_node(4,
                        make_node(5, &SENTINEL)
                    )
                )
            )
        );
    sum = sum_squares(list);

    printf("The sum of squares is: %d\n",sum);
  free_node(list);

  return 0;
}
```

it should equal 55 with the current numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things that you should edit!

- In your `sum_squares` function, your base case checks whether current node `list` is equal to 0, but you should check whether it's the sentinel node.
- In the recursive case, you should use `pow(&list, 2)`. `&list`, however, returns the address of the argument `list`. What you're looking for is the integer value held in the node struct, which you get by using the `->` operator. `&list` becomes `list->value`.
- Finally, when you recursively call your next function, you pass it the same node. This will cause it to infinitely call itself on the same node, and never actually step through the list. Instead of just passing `list` again, you should pass `list->next`!

The changes are applied below:

```
int sum_squares(node* list)
{
    if (list == &SENTINEL)
        return 0;

    return (pow(list->value, 2) + sum_squares(list->next));
}
```

Comment: `pow(list->value, 2)` involves floating point issues and problems that a simple `list->value * list->value` does not.